# How to Concatenate String and Variable with DEFINE in PHP

Tags: php, constants

I have defined a `Constant` viz

```
define('M_3', 'March');
```

if I

```
echo M_3;
```

The output is fine i.e. **March**.

But if do like this

```
$m3 = 3;

echo M_.$m3;
```

The output is **M_3**

Kindly let know where I am mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call a constant with a variable you can use this:

```
echo constant("M_{$m3}");
```

Comment: @Igor_llic; this worked.